# Need advice on database normalization

Tags: oracle, database-design, denormalization

I am working on a basic blood bank database on Oracle. I would like to create a completely basic normalized table and then I will add more details to it. I have done it to the 2NF and I will further proceed on to the 3NF afterwards, but first can someone take a look at my normalization and help me improve it (if needed) or any advices regarding it.

[image: my unnormalized and 1st nf normalized tables]

[image: 2nd nf tables]

Comment: Looks fine to me. What more can be normalized? Seems to me that any further normalization will only introduce unnecessary complications.

Comment: Please provide your table structures as CREATE TABLE blah (FIELD1 TYPE1, F2 T2,.... Fn Tn); and data as INSERT INTO BLAH VALUES (V1, V2,... Vn); Help us to help you.

Comment: To normalize to BCNF or lower forms one must know all functional dependencies. You didn't give them. Are they supposed to be communicated by your sample data? You didn't say. Otherwise, why do you think we can normalize to 2NF without them? Of course we can offer designs based on (hopefully enumerated) guesses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excellent points by @joishi-bodio.

Here's a simple diagram explaining the different entities, attributes, and their relationships in your model.

The first step in modeling any database is to identify the real-world entities; the attributes that define each entity; and then their relationships and cross references.

Here are different observations and conclusions that you may draw from the example -

**Entities and Attributes** -

- The most obvious real-world entity looking at your example is `PERSON`.
- The entity `Person` can be defined with attributes like Name, Age, Gender, DOB, Blood group type
- A `PERSON` can be either a 'Blood Donor' or 'Blood Receiver' or both. 'Donor' and 'Receiver' sound like the different roles that a Person takes, but are not different entities by themselves.
- `Blood Group` can be another entity and can be defined by the name of that blood group among other things.
- In a hospital, blood is stored in blood bags, which could be another entity, defined by who the donor for that blood bag is.
- Transactions is another table which is the store for all blood transactions. A transaction can be defined by a blood bag being assigned to a person (receiver) on a date.

**Relationships**:

- Every person has exactly 1 blood group. You can have 0 or many people with that group.
- Each bloodbag has blood from 1 person. A person may or may not have blood in many blood bags.
- You can assign 0 or many blood bags to a receiver. A person may or may not be a donor to one or many blood bags.

We get something similar to -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`bloodgroup` can be moved to it's own table.. You probably don't need `bloodgroup` at all in the `blood_bag` table, considering that it's always going to match the `donor`'s blood type. Likewise, you shouldn't need the `donor_id` in the `transaction` table since it's always going to match the `blood_bag`'s `donor`.

I'm not really sure why you have a `receiver` table at all ... you probably just want a `person` table that records their name and blood type .. Then both the `transaction` table `donor_id` and `receiver_id` would point to the `person` table. (although, again, that table doesn't need `donor_id` at all..)